# How to generate Kanban with lists based on relationship between Item A, Item B and yet another sub-relationship with Item A?

Tags: google-app-maker, kanban

I am trying to create a Kanban view based on several relationships between datasources.

**The case**

I have: 
- *Tasks* datasource
- *Task_Stages* datasource (e.g. To Do / Doing / Done)
- Tasks many-to-many relationship with Tasks as in Master Task / Sub-Tasks

**The Issue**

I am trying to use grid-layout and its grid-cells as the typical "List" in a Kanban. Where lists are representing the Stages

Within a grid-cell I am trying to set a List-layout widget to represent a typical Kanban item.

If I set the grid's datasource to Task_Stages, each grid-cell would represent a state, e.g. To do / doing / done. In this case, the list-layout widget would show absolutely **all** Task records.

I am struggling to set it to show only Tasks, which are related as Sub-Tasks to a selected Task.

**What I tried**

I've tried a large number of relationship combinations using several layers of panels, but all fail.

e.g. I set up a *Main-Panel* as Task:Sub-Tasks, then the grid as Sub-Task:Stages - in this case it shows only 1 grid cell that represents the stage of the first sub-task record.

This is how it looks with the above example:

[image]

*Only one Stage is shown, instead of showing all stages as different "lists"(grid-cells)

*The tasks visualized in the cell do not bear the relationship with the master task and are just tasks that have that stage type selected

---

Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: If you can post a screen shot of what you are getting and what you want. Also I’m guessing that task stages is it’s own datasource where you can add/remove stages?

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I've added a screenshot above with some additional info on the issue.

The "Task_Stages" is it's own datasource, where I can add and remove stages.

Please refer to the image above. It shows only 1 stage, it should show all existing; The tasks displayed are not related to the master task (the master task is not shown in the shot).

So what is to be achieved: - show all Stages in where a stage is represented in grid-cell; show related "sub-tasks" in the grid-cell of their stage.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa I suspect it shows only 1 stage, because it filters it off of the first item in the sub-task records of the Master-task.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this working correctly you will probably need to do the following:

1. Set your main panel datasource to Stages.
2. In your Stages datasource make sure you don't apply any filters, so
   that all stages will show as in 'To Do/Doing/Done'.
3. Still in your Stages datasource set a prefetch for Tasks, then use
   the 'Advanced' option under prefetch settings to prefetch
   `Tasks.relations.Subtasks`.
4. Back to your main panel, drag in a new Grid or make sure your
   existing grid datasource is set to 'Inherited: Stages'.
5. For reference purposes drag in a label and set the binding to
   `@datasource.item.YourStagesName`, so it will reflect your correct
   stage in each panel. Drag in a list widget into the grid cell and
   set the datasource to 'Stages: Tasks (relation)'.
6. Drag in a list widget into the list row and set the datasource to
   'Tasks: SubTasks (relation)'.

Relatively speaking this should correct your issue but may require some additional testing. I did not test this setup myself but have successfully implemented something similar. The secret here is to prefetch all relations even if they are multiple levels deep by using the advanced prefetch option. Also keep in mind that the more tasks you have the more this process of prefetching multiple relations deep can slow down the performance of your app.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! 

I have successfully implemented part of it.

I have lists with names based on the Stage.

The rest of the implementation is a bit off though.

Issue 1: The first level list, Stages: Tasks (relation), is not filtered based on the currently selected Task and passed info based on all task records.

Issue 2: The second level list, Tasks:Subtasks, lists the subtasks of the tasks, but not in relation of the stage of the subtask. Rather the list is generated based on the stage of the Master task and the subtasks are listed regardless of their stage.

Comment: TL:DR - I have all stages showing as lists, items in nested lists do not reflect selected Parent (Task) or Stage, rather lists contain the Sub-tasks of Tasks which have a the Stage (e.g. Task 1, is in stage To Do => the list shows the Children of Task 1, which can have different stages).